# Entity framework doesn't generate result class

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework, stored-procedures

First of all, I've searched for solutions but maybe I've not done it well because I might be missing some concepts.

So my problem: I'm developing an application to work with a database, using Entity Framework. I create the model using "EF Designer from database", import all tables, functions and stored procedures. The problem comes next. When C# generates the code, it also generates class like "storedProcedureName_Result" which, as the name says, is the result of the stored procedure. C# generates code like:

```
 public virtual ObjectResult<uSP_ListSpecialities_Result> uSP_ListSpecialities()
    {
        return ((IObjectContextAdapter)this).ObjectContext.ExecuteFunction<uSP_ListSpecialities_Result>("uSP_ListSpecialities");
    }
```

and without the result :

```
public virtual ObjectResult<Nullable<int>> uSP_ListAvailableMedicBi()
        {
            return ((IObjectContextAdapter)this).ObjectContext.ExecuteFunction<Nullable<int>>("uSP_ListAvailableMedicBi");
        }
```

I need to use those results but C# does not generate those results to all the stored procedures. And that's my problem, I've no idea why.

e.g :
    This Stored Procedure generates the result class:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE uSP_ListSpecialities
AS
BEGIN
    SELECT  id, nome
    FROM Especialidade 
END
```

it generates an `uSP_ListSpecialities_Result` class

but this one doesn't:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE uSP_ListAvailableMedicBi
AS
BEGIN
    SELECT P.biPessoa
    FROM Pessoa P
        LEFT JOIN Medico M
            ON( M.biPessoa = P.biPessoa)
    WHERE M.biPessoa IS NULL
END
```

I ran both on SQLSMS and both returned what's supposed.

Thank you in advance

Comment: From what I remember, when importing the sp through the designer, you can select Create new complex type.

Comment: @Ric You're right but why someone would want to generate complex result for a procedure which just returns Nullable<int> ?

Comment: No idea, doesn't make too much sense, there maybe a reason?

Comment: @Ric I also found that, the thing is, the complex type does not have the result on the combo box

Comment: I don't want a nullable, that's the point, I want a result class that has a property which is biPessoa

Answer (score 1, accepted):

uSP_ListAvailableMedicBi Procedure returns Nullable Integer so what's the point for generating result class if it's just a standard .NET type ?

EDIT.

According to Your comment. It does return a table for You. It just didn't create a complex type since it's no needed. Snippet below will help You:

```
public List<int> GetAvailableMedicBiList()
{
    using(var ctx = YourEntities())
    {
        return (List<int>)ctx.uSP_ListAvailableMedicBi().ToList();
    }
}
```

Comment: My point is, uSP_ListAvailableMedicBi is supposed to return a table with the P.biPessoa attribute. uSP_ListSpecialities generates a result. Ok, I did not specify the return parameter, but why does one generate a result and the other one generate a nullable?

Comment: Then do as suggested and select the SP in the model browser and create new complex type.

Comment: @DanielS. because first procedure returns table with more than one fields so it had to create a type which holds those fields. The second procedure return just a simple int so why should it create a class for it - it makes no sense

Comment: @MajkeloDev yes, that makes sense. As I said, I'm missing some concepts :) Just another thing. It returns a nullable, but biPessoa is Primary Key from the table Pessoa. Where should I specify that I don't want the nullable value? Because, if I don't specify it i will have a List<int?> and there's no need since I know it will have a value

Comment: If it's a PK it shouldn't create nullable type - that's strange. Go to sql client You are using and make sure that Pessoa.biPessoa is a "int not null" type.

Comment: If You doesn't have Identity on your primary key it may be nullable.

Comment: Agree, check your column specification

Comment: biPessoa (PK, int, not null). I don't have identity, but it shouldn't make it nullable, since it's primary key

Comment: Could it be, since i'm not specifying an output, it's assuming the return value from the store procedure ( I think it has default return int value for error control)

Answer (score 1):

I created a dummy sp returning an `int` and get the following:

[image]

You can see here that I've selected `Complex` as returns collection of and I clicked at the bottom `Create New Complex Type` which created the object for me, which is what I assume you want.

Comment: OP got what he wanted but i can't find a reason for it.

Comment: On your SP, you defined the value as an OUTPUT?

Comment: The sp was more simple than yours, just a `SELECT 1` - that's all.

Comment: Oh, alright. But has @MajkeloDev said, there's no need to generate a class. But thank you for the explanation!

Comment: You could technically create a class that has the property of your column, but for just a single column being returned may not warrant such complexity, the built in types should suffice - the call is yours to make.

Comment: @Ric yes, but I'm new to this (Entity-framwork) so I saw that some SP generated result classes and I was like "oh but some doesn't, what about now" I wasn't thinking straight, if it's only 1 column it makes sense it return the value, not a class. Newbie stuff eheh

Comment: It would make sense to generate a class for returning data with more than one column - because there is no type specific for your purpose. But as each column can map to a data type in the .NET framework, returning one column would map to these making things more simpler.